# Как getText() с одного fxml файла и setText() в другой

Tags: java, xml, javafx, gettext

Есть два **fxml** файла -

> Cont1

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="347.0" prefWidth="641.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="koko1.Cont1Controller">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="Matton" layoutX="242.0" layoutY="258.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="157.0" text="PUSH" />
      <TextField fx:id="text1" layoutX="111.0" layoutY="67.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="419.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="text2" layoutX="111.0" layoutY="109.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="419.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="text4" layoutX="111.0" layoutY="197.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="419.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="text3" layoutX="111.0" layoutY="155.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="419.0" />
      <Button fx:id="close" layoutX="614.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#close" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="30.0" text="Button" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

и

> Cont2

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="183.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="koko1.Cont1Controller">
   <children>
      <TextField fx:id="fill1" layoutX="9.0" layoutY="37.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="165.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="fill2" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="79.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="165.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="fill4" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="163.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="165.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="fill3" layoutX="9.0" layoutY="118.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="165.0" />
      <Button fx:id="close2" layoutY="214.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#close2" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="28.0" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

У каждого по **4 TextField()**.

У Cont1 - **text1**(2,3,4), а у Cont2 **fill1**(2,3,4). Мне нужно, чтобы я мог ввести в text1, text2, text3 и text4 строку, какую захочу, и после нажатия Button()(название у которой Matton)(Сont1 закрывается, открывается Cont2) эти строки появлялись в Cont2 в полях соответственно fill1, fill2, fill3 и fill4. Все они управляются с контроллера **Cont1Controller**.

> Cont1Controller

```
import com.sun.scenario.Settings;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Cont1Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML Button Matton;

    @FXML private Label label;
    @FXML double xOffset = 0;
    @FXML double yOffset = 0;

    @FXML private Button close;
    @FXML private Button close2;

    @FXML String a;
    @FXML String b;
    @FXML String c;
    @FXML String d;

     @FXML private TextField text1; @FXML TextField fill1;
     @FXML private TextField text2; @FXML TextField fill2;

     @FXML private TextField text3; @FXML TextField fill3;
     @FXML private TextField text4; @FXML TextField fill4;


@FXML public void close2(ActionEvent event) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) close2.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
} 
@FXML public void close(ActionEvent event) {
    Stage stage = (Stage) close.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
} 

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException  {

      text1 = new TextField();    a = new String(); fill1 = new TextField();
      text2 = new TextField();    b = new String(); fill2 = new TextField();

      text3 = new TextField();    c = new String(); fill3 = new TextField();  
      text4 = new TextField();    d = new String(); fill4 = new TextField();  

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader2 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("windows/Cont2.fxml"));

                Parent root2 = (Parent) fxmlLoader2.load();
                Stage stage2 = new Stage();
                Scene mscene = new Scene(root2);
               //new Settings().start(new Scene(mscene));

                stage2.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
                stage2.setScene(mscene); 

       a=   (String) text1.getUserData();
        b=   (String) text2.getUserData();
        c=   (String) text3.getUserData();
        d=   (String) text4.getUserData();

            fill1.setUserData(a);
            fill2.setUserData(b);
            fill3.setUserData(c);
            fill4.setUserData(d);


        root2.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event1) -> {
            xOffset = event1.getSceneX();
            yOffset = event1.getSceneY();
        });
        root2.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event1) -> {
            stage2.setX(event1.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            stage2.setY(event1.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        });



        ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();

                stage2.show();

          }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO

    }      
}
```

Еще есть основной java.class

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


public class Koko1 extends Application {
    @FXML double xOffset = 0;
    @FXML double yOffset = 0;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage1) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader1 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("windows/Cont1.fxml"));
                Parent root1 =  fxmlLoader1.load();
                Scene mscene = new Scene(root1);

                //beauty 
                 // Image m_image = new Image("/mini-icon.png");
                 //  stage2.getIcons().addAll(m_image);
                stage1.setTitle("Banananaaaaa");

                stage1.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT); 



        root1.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event1) -> {
            xOffset = event1.getSceneX();
            yOffset = event1.getSceneY();
        });
        root1.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event1) -> {
            stage1.setX(event1.getScreenX() - xOffset);
            stage1.setY(event1.getScreenY() - yOffset);
        });


        stage1.setScene(mscene);
        stage1.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы заработало, можно сделать следующие вещи:

1) полностью удалить этот код

```
  text1 = new TextField();    a = new String(); fill1 = new TextField();
  text2 = new TextField();    b = new String(); fill2 = new TextField();

  text3 = new TextField();    c = new String(); fill3 = new TextField();  
  text4 = new TextField();    d = new String(); fill4 = new TextField();
```

, т.к. вы переинициализируете `TextField`'*ы*, т.е. теряете ссылки на объекты

2) Вместо

```
a = (String) text1.getUserData();
b = (String) text2.getUserData();
c = (String) text3.getUserData();
d = (String) text4.getUserData();

fill1.setUserData(a);
fill2.setUserData(b);
fill3.setUserData(c);
fill4.setUserData(d);
```

написать

```
fill1.setText(text1.getText());
fill2.setText(text2.getText());
fill3.setText(text3.getText());
fill4.setText(text4.getText());
```

3) Есть некая проблема в инициализации второго `fxml`, в которой мне было лень разбираться, поэтому написал по своему. Убрал ссылку на контроллер в `Cont2.fxml`:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="183.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

Явно указал в коде:

```
  ...
  fxmlLoader2.setController( this );
  Parent root2 = (Parent) fxmlLoader2.load();
  Stage stage2 = new Stage();
  ...
```

**Пару замечаний:**

1) Аннотация `@FXML` для локальных переменных не нужна

```
@FXML String a;
@FXML String b;
```

2) Этот метод вызовется дважды для каждого из `fxml`, так что наверное `не TODO`

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO

}
```

**UPDATE**

Проблема инициализации второго `fxml` в том, что `FXMLLoader` создаёт новый контроллер( в смысле объект ), который ничем не связан с первым. Решение выше исправляет это.